# Range Query in Elasticsearch Doesn't Filter on Certain Number Fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running the following query against my ES instance `5.4`. My year range and postal code works great, but as soon as I add in the price or millage range, it returns zero results. Here's the cURL statement (I converted it as I'm running the ES PHP library, so my syntax may be off here).

Additionally, I've also moved the price & milage to a `filter` bool with no tangible results.

In my ES instance I have a Suzuki that match this criterial.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                {"query_string" : {
                    "query" : "suzuki",
                    "fields" : {"keywords", "description", "title"}
                }},
                {"range" : {
                    "year.keyword" : {
                        "gte" : 2010,
                        "lte" : 1980
                    }
                }},
                {"range" : {
                    "price.keyword" : {
                        "gte" : 0,
                        "lte" : 10000
                    }
                }},
                {"range" : {
                    "mileage.keyword" : {
                        "gte" : 0,
                        "lte" : 100000
                    }
                }},
                {"terms" : {
                    "postal.keyword" : 57013
                }}
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "*" : { "force_source" : "true", "fragment_size" : 250 }
        }
    },
    "sort" : {
        "price.keyword" : { "order" : "asc", "mode" : "min" }
    }
}'
```

Here is the Suzuki ES record (some of this has been scrubbed):

```
_source: {
index: "",
type: "",
keywords: "2009 Suzuki Sx4 Crossover AWD Crossover 4dr 4A",
description: "2009 Suzuki SX4 Crossover AWD Crossover 4dr 4A",
title: "2009 Suzuki Sx4 Crossover AWD Crossover 4dr 4A,
postal: "57013",
price: "5600",
year: "2009",
make: "Suzuki",
model: "sx4",
mileage: "93012",
engine: "2.0L I4",
transmission: "Automatic",
trim: "AWD Crossover 4dr ",
date_added: "2017-10-01 01:48:36",
date_updated: "2017-10-01 01:48:36"
}
```

Comment: can you add your schema mappings and settings as well

Comment: possibly this can help https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html

Comment: Thanks @user3775217 - after checking my mappings, it looks like those fields are set to text. I'm going to reindex, map those fields differently and see if that helps.

Comment: yeah, i was also doubting that field may have been text, should work fine once you reindex and coerce defaults to true for integer fields

Comment: As you said in a comment, your mappings are set to text, but you are attempting to use a range query as if they are an int or double.  Consider doing a date format of `year` for the car's year and a double on price.

Comment: Ah, thanks @ryanlutgen for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the types of a few fields and that seemed to do the trick. Here's what I ultimately posted to my index.

```
url -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "price": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "mileage": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "postal": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "year": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy||epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```